# WPF Canvas scale transform translate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I'm currently facing a problem with `ItemsControl` and canvas in WPF.

**What I'm trying to do :**

- Add `Points` to an `ItemsControl` and store their coordinates as a percentage/fraction relative to this `ItemsControl` size
- Load them in another `ItemsControl` with their coordinates as percentage of this new `ItemsControl`

**Example of what I want to achieve :**

- `ItemsControl` **ContainerA** is a square of 100 by 100. I add a new Point **P1** at X=10 and Y=10.
- I save **P1** with X=0.1 and Y=0.1 (10% of **ContainerA** size)
- I load **P1** in `ItemsControl` **ContainerB**, a square of 500 by 500, P1 coordinates should be x=50 and Y=50 (10% of **ContainerB** size)

How would one accomplish this ?

Knowing that converters are not an option, and neither is `ScaleTransform` as  my `Points` may help to display text / pictures / whatever and I don't want them to be scaled with the new container.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I would probably write a [custom Canvas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element) with Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top in relative coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to obtain what I wanted by creating a custom ItemsControl and an interface IScalableVm.

```
public class ScaleItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);
        ScaleItems();
    }

    protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
    {
        base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
        ScaleItems();
    }

    private void ScaleItems()
    {
        foreach (var item in ItemsSource.OfType<IScalableVm>())
        {
            item.Scale(this.RenderSize.Width, this.RenderSize.Height);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I just scale the coordinates of my IScaleVms (my points for example) by multiplying their coordinates with the new width and height of this container.

```
public virtual void Scale(double width, double height)
{
    Position = new Point(width * _model.StartPosition.X, height * _model.StartPosition.Y);
}
```

It's far from being perfect. I still believe there is a way to do this in pure WPF style, but I don't know it